# How to show element of VueJS component only if this component has v-on attached?

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS component. I need to show some part of it if there is handler for 'event' event.

```html
<!-- here is my simple component -->
<cmp v-on:event='foo'></cmp>

<!-- here its template -->
<div id='cmpTemplate'>
  <p>Show it only if v-on:event is not empty</p>
<div>
```

Adding additional property is not so neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components have `$listeners` property which is the dictionary of functions that are bound to the component on `v-on`, and I think you could use it for this.

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html :

```
{
  focus: function (event) { /* ... */ }
  input: function (value) { /* ... */ },
}
```

But I'd advise you to follow @kat advise and not to do that. This feels like it was not designed for this, and just think of this more: do you want to have a component that changes its behavior depending on whether it is viewed by something else? Unless you design quantum particle, this is not how components should work in my mind.

---

I just realized that I have seen the behavior like you want before (although I still think that it's not worth doing for the buttons, like you comment suggest) - but maybe this will work for you better. Have a look at: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table This is a table, that has a `provider` prop that can be a function. It changes the behavior whether you set `provider` or not - if you do not, it does not invoke the function, but go for `item` property to get the data out.

This is done, by using `v-bind` instead of `v-on`, but the binding is done to the function. This might be better approach as you don't have to use `$listeners` anymore and it gives an insight that the behavior is changed depending on whether you set the property to a function or to `null`

Comment: Actually, this component is a set of controls and buttons that allow to do something. I think, it is quite good solution if i need to show only buttons that has actions attached. Or maybe I want to disable controls that has no action.

Comment: Solution: `<p v-if="$listeners.hasOwnProperty('event')">...</p>`

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen Please also see my edit, maybe the other approach would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

I would define and send the vOnStatus = true for attached v-on:event
and then do v-if="vOnStatus" for the elements I want to display

Comment: I think you mean <cmp v-on:event='foo' vOnStatus='true'></cmp>. But it duplicates existing information. Accepted if only component can't get information about his event listeners.

Comment: vOnStatus="true" would be defined when v-on:event is triggered or gets emitted and we can condition its elements to be displayed/or not, But i think There is no way to check whether dynamically attached event listeners exist or not.